# Are Markov Random Fields implemented in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Markov Random Fields are a really popular way to look at an image, but I can't find a direct reference to them being implemented in OpenCV.  Perhaps they are named differently, or are built from some indirect method.

As the title states, are MRFs implemented in OpenCV?  And if not, what is the popular way to represent them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**OpenCV deals mostly with statistical machine learning** rather than things that go under the name *Bayesian Networks*, *Markov Random Fields*, or *graphical models*.](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&pg=PA459&lpg=PA459&dq=markov%20random%20fields%20opencv&source=bl&ots=hSG0bieBQe&sig=G-4jiy4qtqDYGYp5WqRjSbpKF8A&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=zNlPT5OVK4mtgwf6p7DmDQ&ved=0CGQQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=markov%20random%20fields%20opencv&f=false)

Comment: an english language link: http://books.google.com/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&pg=PA459&dq=markov+random+fields+opencv&hl=en&sa=X&ei=t4pQT8_4M4G_0QX1iI3-Cw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=markov%20random%20fields%20opencv&f=false

Comment: Well observed, my young padawan.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  How do people go about representing them with opencv then?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8580389/176769) and [this](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2010/05/05/bust-out-your-own-graphcut-based-image-segmentation-with-opencv-w-code/) post for ideas.