# Comparing focus of 2 image

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to develop object detection algorithm. I plan to compare 2 image with different focus length. One image that correct focus on the object and one image that correct focus on background.

By reading about [autofocus algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autofocus#Passive_autofocus). I think it can done with contrast detection passive autofocus algorithm. It work on light intensity on the sensor.

But I don't sure that light intensity value from the image file has the same value as from the sensor. (it not a RAW image file. a jpeg image.) Is the light intensity value in jpeg image were the same as on the sensor? Can I use it to detect focus correctness with contrast detection? Is there a better way to detect which area of image were correct focus on the image?

Comment: Can you please upload sample images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to process the images a bit and I saw some progress. THis is what I did using opencv:

- converted images to gray using cvtColor(I, Mgrey, CV_RGB2GRAY);
- downsampled/decimated them a bit since they are huge (several Mb)
- Took the sum of absolute horizontal and vertical gradients using http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=sobel#cv.Sobel.
  The result is below. The foreground when in focus does look brighter than background and vice versa.

[image]

[image]

You can probably try to match and subtract these images using translation from [matchTemplate()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#cv.MatchTemplate) on the original gray images; and then assemble pieces using the convex hull of the results as initialization mask for [grab cut](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=grab%20cut#cv2.grabCut) and plugging in color images. In case you aren’t familiar with the grab cut, chceck out my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22053017/457687).

But may be a simpler method will work here as well. You can try to apply a strong [blur](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=blur#cv2.blur) to your gradient images instead of precise matching and see what the difference give you in this case. The images below demonstrate the idea when I turned the difference in the binary masks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that the object will shift when the focus were change then we can't matched and compare it preciously.
Something maybe done by compare the brightness of these first result. I don't sure when. But I will update it result again when I have a time to try.

Comment: May be not precisely, but the last two images are quite OK to distinguish between blurred background and foreground.

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful to see your images. It I understood you correctly you try to separate background from foreground using focus (or blur) cue. Contrast in the image depends on focus but it **also** depend on the contrast of the target. So if the target is clouds you will never get sharp edges or high contrast. Finally jpeg image that use little compression should not affect the critical properties of your algorithm.

I would try to get a number of images at all possible focus lengths in a row and then build a graph of the contrast as a function of focal length (or even better focusing distance). The peak in this graph will give you the distance to the object regardless of object's own contrast. Note, however, that the accuracy of such visual cues goes down sharply with viewing distance.

This is what I expect you to obtain when measuring the sum of absolute [gradient](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=sobel#cv.Sobel) in a small window:

[image]

The next step for you will be to combine areas that are in focus with the areas that are solid color that is has no particular peak in the graph but none the less belong to the same object. Sometimes getting a [convex hull](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=convex%20hull#cv.ConvexHull2) of the focused areas can help to pinpoint the raw boundary of the object.

Comment: The image will look like this.

[object focused](https://gvupyg.dm1.livefilestore.com/y2pvJenhYNIUlQyFHSH_MawpX8CVpE09FW9y5MS4weSl3gvwYWixNiGlczwJHh-w_utaBwzI8WH5XKAcQtQ-fk1NATALcMjDOW-PjmgJORn8OM/WP_20140301_12_54_02_Pro.jpg?psid=1)

And [background focused](https://gvupyg.dm2301.livefilestore.com/y2p7iLR9pFCcHm5aE7G7xDpZ0F91wlN8jj5qSpDHQeLsNVTcu4Potd8Uf7UIo81nDfxBBJK4yGOKVhSlD6ZWMcs5_NwTcsM2OEeWHrE9KowCKU/WP_20140301_12_54_12_Pro.jpg?psid=1)

You understand it correctly. In this sample image I want to know area of the focused object (a can) and a background.

Comment: That mean I have to comparing it with all area to know which area have a correct focus and which area were not?

Comment: I loaded your images and compared them. Unfortunately they were shifted during refocusing so I cannot subtract their gradient to find the area that is more focused. Will come back to you with more thought/results.