# HMM for image sequence classification in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, hidden-markov-models

I am trying to classify 9 types of crops (Y) from 5 satellite images (X), acquired at dates t = {t1,...,t5}, corresponding to 5 crop phrenology states (S) i.e.  preparation, seeding, growing, harvesting and post-harvesting stages. I am using similar training parcels throughout therefore the prior probabilities (initial probabilities) are equal. I have computed the likelihood model (Emission Probabilities) P(X|Y) from each image using Gaussian mixture model and I have state Transition probabilities for each crop. My question is how do I integrate this into HMM using this [library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cvhmm/) to determine the final class of each pixel {using HMM posterior probability model equation below} in a final image of the area?  So far I have looked at the example used here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015009/hidden-markov-model-training-for-dynamic-gestures) but it is still not clear for me.

HMMM model equation:

[image]

Kindly advice.
regards.